# Error loading class 'com.spotify.docker.Resource'

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spotify, docker-maven-plugin

I am trying to build and push a docker image using docker maven plugin spotify version 1.0.0.

But, the docker build has failed with the below error,

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build: Error loading class 'com.spotify.docker.Resource'
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:593)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:525)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:98)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Error loading class 'com.spotify.docker.Resource'
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.CollectionConverter.fromConfiguration(CollectionConverter.java:174)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:260)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:563)
... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spotify.docker.Resource
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.CollectionConverter.fromConfiguration(CollectionConverter.java:161)
... 37 more
```

My POM.xml configuration is

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>sample-boot:latest</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>target/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <pushImage>true</pushImage>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Any reason you are using version `1.0.0` as opposed to `1.2.2`

Comment: Also, did you add this plugin as a dependency? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/docker-maven-plugin/1.2.2